# Unable to open json file in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, web

I have a local json file in the same directory as the js file and index.html file. I am using firefox to view my website since chrome did not allow cross origin http requests. Here is my angular code:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('contactPage',[]);

app.controller('contactController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){


    $http.get('contacts.json').then(function(data){
        $scope.contactList = data;
    })
}]);

})();
```

But this is giving me two errors in Firefox:
XML parsing error, syntax location error for the JSON file and a 'possibly unhandled rejection'.

[image: Screenshot of errors]

Comment: show `contacts.json` content. your json is invalid

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$http/baddata